# Treating a percentage over 100% as a double digit %

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV containing some raw data. I am dropping rows conditionally but am running into an issue when there is a percentage > 100%. The percentage appears to be treated like a double digit %.

Here is my function to transform this dataframe. The purpose is to delete all rows with a percentage >= 50% & percentage < 0% & percentage == 0% in specified column; then sort descending by that column. I'm sure I can combine all drop transformations, but I like the readability of this one.

```
def modify_csv():
    df = pd.read_csv("Initial.csv")

    # Delete row if utb > 50%
    df.drop(df[df["column 1"] >= "50%"].index, inplace = True)

    # Delete row if utb == 0%
    df.drop(df[df["column 1"] == "0%"].index, inplace = True)

    # Delete row if utb == 0%
    df.drop(df[df["column 1"] < "0%"].index, inplace = True)

    # Sort by column 1
    df.sort_values(by = "column 1", ascending = False, inplace = True)

    df.to_csv("Final.csv", na_rep = 0, index = False)
```

This is the output for for my most recent run of "column 1":

```
49%
48%
47%
45%
39%
36%
27%
19%
17%
111%
104%
```

Everything is working great except you can see that 111% and 104% are being treated like they are equal to 11% an 10%, as we are descendingly sorting. Any insight would be appreciated! I scoured online but couldn't find any similar cases. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing numeric comparisons, convert numeric strings to numbers:

```
def modify_csv():
    df = pd.read_csv("Initial.csv")
    df['percent'] = pd.to_numeric(df["column 1"].str.rstrip('%'))
    df = df.loc[(df['percent'] < 50) & (df['percent'] > 0)]
    df = df.sort_values(by="percent", ascending=False)
    # Instead, you may want to keep the percent column and drop column 1, because numbers are more useful than numeric strings,
    # and whoever reads Final.csv may end up needing to strip the % signs again...
    df = df.drop('percent', axis=1)
    df.to_csv("Final.csv", na_rep=0, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! Similar to the first comment with some great example. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the sort order isn't that it's being treated as double digit percentage, but rather because the data is being treated as string. String is compared lexicographically.

You'd need to set [`dtype` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) when calling `read_csv` to make sure your data is treated as numbers. You may also need to use `converters` to strip the percentage sign.

Comment: Great thanks Lie. The next section of my function converted that column to_numeric so I could get the mean of that column. I moved the to_numeric to before my code above and everything is working now. Thanks for the help.